# Create a hash of matching words, occurrence

Tags: ruby, hash

I am working on a ruby program that will take a string and compare it to a "dictionary" of words and will return a hash with what words match and how many times they match. So far I am able to iterate through the string and the array and it will return a string when it finds a match, but I don't know how to create a hash with the matching word and the occurrence. Here is the code-

```
dictionary = ["below","down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part","partner","sit"]

def substrings (string, dictionary)
  dictionary = dictionary
  words = string.split(/\s+/)
  puts words
  x = 0
  while x < words.length do
    y = 0
    while y < dictionary.length do
      if words[x] == dictionary[y] 
      puts "it's working"
    end
    y += 1 
  end   
  x += 1
  end
end

substrings("let's go down below", dictionary)
```

Any ideas on how to make the hash would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When giving an example, it's best to show your desired or expected output. I suggest you edit to do that, perhaps right after defining `dictionary`. It was good that you included the local variable `dictionary`, so that readers can refer to it without having to define it.

Comment: Have a look at Ruby Hash documentation - there are examples on how to create it and access it - http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html

Comment: This is actually two questions: "How do I count the frequency of words in a string?", and "How do I extract specific values from a hash?" Research those and you'll have your answer. Hint, these are very common questions on Stack Overflow so you should have no problem finding answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meditate on this:

```
'b c c d'.split # => ["b", "c", "c", "d"]
'b c c d'.split.group_by{ |w| w } # => {"b"=>["b"], "c"=>["c", "c"], "d"=>["d"]}
'b c c d'.split.group_by{ |w| w }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.count] } # => [["b", 1], ["c", 2], ["d", 1]]
'b c c d'.split.group_by{ |w| w }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.count] }.to_h # => {"b"=>1, "c"=>2, "d"=>1}
```

From that we can build:

```
dictionary = ['b', 'c']
word_count = 'b c c d'.split.group_by{ |w| w }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.count] }.to_h
word_count.values_at(*dictionary) # => [1, 2]
```

If you only want key/value pairs that are in the dictionary, you can do that easily:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/slice'
word_count.slice(*dictionary) # => {"b"=>1, "c"=>2}
```

[`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) is a very useful method that groups by whatever criteria you pass to it. [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.4/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) takes a list of "keys" and returns their corresponding values.

There are potential problems when counting "words", because not all text results in what we'd consider a word after splitting it into its component sub-strings. For instance:

```
'how now brown cow.'.split # => ["how", "now", "brown", "cow."]
```

Notice that the final word has the punctuation included in the string. Similarly, compound words and other punctation can cause problems:

```
'how-now brown, cow.'.split # => ["how-now", "brown,", "cow."]
```

The task then becomes how to remove those from being considered as parts of the words. The simple thing is to simply strip them out:

```
'how-now brown, cow.'.gsub(/[^a-z]+/, ' ').split # => ["how", "now", "brown", "cow"]
```

In today's crazy age though, we see words that contain digits too, especially things like company and program names. You can modify the pattern in `gsub` above to handle that, but how is left for you to figure out.

We also see mixed case, so your dictionary needs to be folded to upper-case or lower-case, and the string being considered needs to also be folded the same way, *unless* you want to know the different counts when honoring character case:

```
word_count = 'b C c d'.downcase.split.group_by{ |w| w }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.count] }.to_h # => {"b"=>1, "c"=>2, "d"=>1}
word_count = 'b C c d'.split.group_by{ |w| w }.map{ |k, v| [k, v.count] }.to_h # => {"b"=>1, "C"=>1, "c"=>1, "d"=>1}
```

Analyzing the content of pages often starts with this sort of code, but many rules have to be written to specify what are useful words and what are garbage. And, the rules often change from one source to another as their use of words and numbers can break the usefulness of your code quickly:

```
second
2nd
```

for instance. It gets "interesting".

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it:

```
def substrings (string, dictionary)
  dictionary.each.with_object({}){|w, h| h[w] = string.scan(/\b#{w}\b/).length}
end

substrings("let's go down below", dictionary)
```

output:

```
{
  "below"   => 1,
  "down"    => 1,
  "go"      => 1,
  "going"   => 0,
  "horn"    => 0,
  "how"     => 0,
  "howdy"   => 0,
  "it"      => 0,
  "i"       => 0,
  "low"     => 0,
  "own"     => 0,
  "part"    => 0,
  "partner" => 0,
  "sit"     => 0
}
```

Comment: I always prefer solutions to string problems that, as yours, deal with the string directly, rather than first breaking it into an array of substrings.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is to create what is sometimes called a "counting hash":

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

Here zero is the "default value". That means that if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` *returns* zero (but the hash is not altered). Then you will have:

```
h[k] += 1
```

which expands to:

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

If `h` has a key `k`, `h[k]` on right will have a value, so [Bob's your uncle](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/why-do-we-say-bobs-your-uncle). If, however, `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` on the right is set to the default value, so the expression becomes:

```
h[k] = 0 + 1
```

Cool, eh?

So for your problem you can write:

```
dictionary = %w| below down go going horn how howdy it i low own part partner sit |
  #=> ["below", "down", "go", "going", "horn", "how", "howdy", "it", "i",
  #    "low", "own", "part", "partner", "sit"] 
string = "Periscope down, so we can go down, way down, below the surface."

string.delete(',.').split.downcase.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word,h|
  (h[word] += 1) if dictionary.include?(word) }
  #=> {"down"=>3, "go"=>1, "below"=>1}
```

You might also see this written:

```
string.delete(',.').downcase.split.each_with_object({}) do |word,h|
  h[word.downcase] = (h[word] || 0) + 1 if dictionary.include?(word) }
```

so if `h` does not have a key `word`, `h[word]` will be `nil`, so the expression becomes:

```
h[word] = (h[word] || 0) + 1
  #=>   = (nil     || 0) + 1
  #=>   = 0 + 1
```

Another approach is to first count the number of instances of each word in `string` then see which are in the dictionary:

```
h = string.delete(',.').downcase.split.group_by(&:itself)
  #=> {"periscope"=>["periscope"], "down"=>["down", "down", "down"], "so"=>["so"],
  #    "we"=>["we"], "can"=>["can"], "go"=>["go"], "way"=>["way"], "below"=>["below"],
  #    "the"=>["the", "the"], "surface"=>["surface"]}
h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[k] = v.size if dictionary.include?(k) }
  #=> {"down"=>3, "go"=>1, "below"=>1}
```

(Edit: see @theTinMan's answer for better ways of using [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)).

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of description of counting `Hash` given by [Cary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361639/794242), your code can be modified slightly as below.

```
dictionary = ["below","down","go","going","horn","how","howdy","it","i","low","own","part","partner","sit"]

def substrings (string, dictionary)

  words = string.split(/\s+/)

  count_hash = Hash.new(0)

  words.each do |sentence_word|
    dictionary.each do |dictionary_word|
        if sentence_word == dictionary_word
            count_hash[sentence_word] += 1
        end
    end   
  end

  return count_hash
end

p substrings("let's go down below", dictionary)
```

However, given that there is a method [`Array#count`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-count), we could take its advantage and reduce the above code to something like below. In this version, we don't need counting hash.

```
def substrings (string, dictionary)
  words = string.split(/\s+/)
  count_hash = Hash.new

  dictionary.each do |dictionary_word|
    if (count = words.count(dictionary_word)) > 0
        count_hash[dictionary_word] = count
    end
  end   

  return count_hash
end
```

You can refer to other answers for more idiomatic Ruby solutions.  If I had to take a stab at it, below would be my version

```
def substrings (string, dictionary)
  words = string.split(/\s+/)
  dictionary.map { |d| [d, words.count(d)] }.to_h.reject  {|_, v| v == 0}
end
```

Comment: You're not Wand Maker. Wand has a pointy head.

Comment: @CarySwoveland None of the winter bash hats were looking neat when I had my pointy hat on.  So temporarily its hats-off

Comment: A variant: `words = string.split; (dictionary & words).map { |w| [w, words.count(w)] }.to_h`. (Note `str.split` is the same as `str.split(/\s+/)`.)